# My facebook app isn't loading. ERROR: Operation Timed Out

Tags: facebook-apps

Some people have asked questions like this, but none of them are answered for some reason, so I am asking again:
I have created a new facebook app and created a basic HTML page, the contents of which are copied from the "authentication" sample on the Facebook developers site. I am always getting an "Operation Timed Out" message in the middle of the canvas (ther other facebook parts are loading perfectly).
I have tried with different URLs, different page contents, and only 1 success - when I loaded the AMAZON.com page in my app :)
My pages work fine when called normally through a browser by the way.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a secure URL (https) for your app? If you have, is your SSL certificate valid (might have expired)?

SSL support for page tabs has been mandatory since October 1, 2011.

You probably already reviewed this info, but just in case here's the [Facebook Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs) with screenshots and step by step setup.